# How to call functions from a vararg-parameter?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to call functions which are contained in a vararg-parameter?

```
def perform(functions:() => Unit*) = ?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, very possible:

```
>> def perform(functions:() => Unit*) = for (f <- functions) f()
>> perform(() => println("hi"), () => println("bye"))    
hi
bye
perform: (functions: () => Unit*)Unit
```

Remember that repeated parameters are exposed as `Seq[TheType]`. In this case, `Seq[() => Unit]`, although it can be sort of confusing as it *looks* like the `*` should have higher precedence, but it does not.

Note that using parenthesis yields the same type:

```
>> def perform(functions:(() => Unit)*) = for (f <- functions) f()
perform: (functions: () => Unit*)Unit
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

@pst gave you the answer, I'm just adding another bit for future reference.

Let's say you find yourself with the following collection of functions:

```
val fcts = List(() => println("I hate"), () => println("this"))
```

If you try to execute this in the REPL

```
perform(fcts) // this does not compile
```

won't work.

However you can tell the compiler that what you are really trying to achieve is to pass the list as a Java array (this is how varargs are represented in the bytecode)

```
perform(fcts : _*) // works.
```

Clearly, this hold for any Scala collection, not just List.

Comment: In Ruby, we call this "splatting" the arguments.